# How to speed up a "decay" ffill function for pandas Series?

Tags: python, pandas, performance

I want to speed up the following implementation of my "decay" forward fill function, which fills zero values with the last nonzero value times a decaying factor `alpha ** (t-T)` in which `0<alpha<1` and `(t-T)` is the distance from the last nonzero value:

```py
def decay_series(s):
    decay_fac = 0.9
    for i in range(1, len(s)):
        if abs(s.iloc[i]) < 1e-6:
            s.iloc[i] = s.iloc[i - 1] * decay_fac
    return s
s = pd.Series([0,0, 1, 2, 0,0,1,0,0,1])
s
Out[24]: 
0    0
1    0
2    1
3    2
4    0
5    0
6    1
7    0
8    0
9    1
dtype: int64
decay_series(s)
Out[25]: 
0    0.00
1    0.00
2    1.00
3    2.00
4    1.80
5    1.62
6    1.00
7    0.90
8    0.81
9    1.00
dtype: float64
```

However this is too slow due to the usage of pure python for loop. Is there anyway to speed this up, e.g., by some clever application of `pandas`'s native components? It seems that, unfortunately, `fillna` or `replace` methods don't support custom user methods to be applied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Using `mask` and broadcasting

```
(s.mask(s.eq(0)).ffill() * decay_fac ** s.groupby(s.ne(0).cumsum()).cumcount()).fillna(0)
```

---

```
0    0.00
1    0.00
2    1.00
3    2.00
4    1.80
5    1.62
6    1.00
7    0.90
8    0.81
9    1.00
dtype: float64
```

#### `timings`

9.62 milliseconds vs 1.12 seconds for 10000 rows

```
%timeit (s.mask(s.eq(0)).ffill() * 0.9 ** s.groupby(s.ne(0).cumsum()).cumcount()).fillna(0)
9.62 ms ± 206 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit decay_series(s)
1.12 s ± 161 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```